# PHP inside of PHP, How to?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, printf, echo

Im am trying to add a php to dynamically display rss within the search results pages on my WordPress site. The $XMLFILE below is suppose to have the url to the rss feed I want to display.

```
$XMLFILE = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=SEARCH-QUERY-GOES-HERE&format=rss";
```

Now, the thing is I want to use another php in the $XMLFILE where it says SEARCH-QUERY-GOES-HERE. Like this example:

```
$XMLFILE = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=<?php printf( __( '%s', 'twentytwelve' ), '' . get_search_query() . '' ); ?>&format=rss";
```

Problem is, how do I put php inside of this to complete the url?

This php I got from wordpress and display the search term searched on the site

```
<?php printf( __( '%s', 'twentytwelve' ), '' . get_search_query() . '' ); ?>
```

SO now I have been trying to put the two together so when the user searches may APPLES it will show in the $XMLFILE where it say SEARCH-QUERY-GOES-HERE the word APPLES and therefore displays the rss for the keyword APPLES. APPLES is just the example keyword I used to try to illustrate what I am asking.

Get what I am asking? ANyone know how to add php inside php like this or a better option to add a Wordpress search term into $XMLFILE where it says SEARCH-QUERY-GOES-HERE?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't embed PHP in PHP like that, unless you're using `eval()`. And as a general rule, `eval()` is an evil ugly tool that should never be used - it **WILL** blow up on you horribly at some point.

Comment: @Frederik answered the question just fine and his response worked. Thanks anyways guys. No need to use eval() code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand this question, you could do something like this:

```
$more = __( get_search_query(), 'twentytwelve' );
$XMLFILE = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=$more&format=rss";
```

In double-quotes, variables can be placed inline. As done above. You can then run `__()` above, and put the result in a variable. This will get the wanted result.